# On using Tag-only edits for post visibility/categorization

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Other posts on meta about tag-only edits mostly revolve around editors bulk editing to add tags just because they can; adding Language X to any post tagged with Library Q, for instance. Tag-only edits seem to be largely considered non-substantial (for good reason), and are somewhat discouraged for taking up more time in approval queue. However, because of this, seem prone to rejection.

What I'm concerned with are cases where the tag is edited because it is simply wrong--either tags which would be important to finding an answer *aren't* included, or tags which are irrelevant *are*. From my own suggestion history, [this tag only edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23546176) is an example. Knowing what I know now, I might have cut down on the extraneous bits of text, but the core issue is that what OP wants to do involves using API G, not language G.

In this case, there's a fair amount of overlap in the people who might be answering questions on API G and Language G, although they're fairly separate entities; using the Language would do no good for OP's question, but the API would. In worse situations, there's little or no overlap, as the two tags may seem superficially similar, but lead to two completely technologies, tools, languages, communities, etc.

How should tag editing be handled so that questions are categorized correctly, can be seen by those who watch the tag, and won't show up in unrelated tags? Should editors try to fix just the tags and leave further editing to the OP/those who follow the tag and presumably know more about the content? Should they edit the question to the best of their ability, despite potentially lacking knowledge/context on its content matter? Should editors leave the post alone and wait for someone else to fix the tags in another edit?

Comment: General consensus is for tag-only edits to be done by users with full editing privileges (as they are minor changes), so they don't have to be reviewed.